# SpringBoot JPA Many-to-Many relationship - Rest Webservice unable to get all child attributes in Get All

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jackson, many-to-many

I have a simple many to many relationship : `Owner <-> Book <-> Publisher`

I notice an odd behavior: When I get the specific `Book`, the `Publisher` and `Owner` (child entities) information is fetched along with all attributes. However, in `Get` All `Book`s, the child’s attributes are missing.

When I do a `GET` to a specific `Book`, I get all attributes of both `Book` and its child:

```
cURL -XGET http://localhost:8080/books/isbn/978-0743246264

{
   "id":4,
   "name":"Book 4",
   "isbn":"978-0743246264",
   "publishers":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Publisher 1",
         "description":"Description - 1"
      }
   ],
   "owners":[
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"Owner 3"
      }
   ]
}
```

However, when I run `GET` for all books, the child attributes are missing for some elements:

```
cURL -XGET http://localhost:8080/books

[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Book 1",
      "isbn":"978-0743246261",
      "publishers":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Publisher 1",
            "description":"Description - 1"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Publisher 2",
            "description":"Description - 2"
         }
      ],
      "owners":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Owner 1"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Book 2",
      "isbn":"978-0743246262",
      "publishers":[
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Publisher 4",
            "description":"Description - 4"
         },
         1,
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Publisher 3",
            "description":"Description - 3"
         }
      ],
      "owners":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Owner 2"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Owner 3"
         },
         1
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Book 3",
      "isbn":"978-0743246263",
      "publishers":[
         4,
         2
      ],
      "owners":[
         2
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Book 4",
      "isbn":"978-0743246264",
      "publishers":[
         1
      ],
      "owners":[
         3
      ]
   }
]
```

I’ve setup the project on GitHub and it is ready to run and test right away: https://github.com/tekpartner/learn-spring-boot-many-2-many

Comment: It has to do with your code, obviously. Specifically to the Jackson annotations on the classes you're returning. But you didn't post the code,so... check the annotations you chose to put on your properties, and read their documentation.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, you were on target. I got it fixed and checked in the code to the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [@JsonIdentityInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) annotation from both `Publisher` and `Owner` class, so Jackson will serialize a full version of the class instead of using their `id` as a reference.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That worked for me. BTW, the code is located here -> https://github.com/tekpartner/learn-spring-boot-many-2-many

Comment: @ToraToraTora glad to hear that, I've checked your Github code to solve it.